# How to wifi scan on android marshmallow? add ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Tags: android

My device sdk version 25 and marshmallow.

so, I use wifi scan this source.

```
public List<String> getScanWifiResult() {
   List<ScanResult> result;

   mWifiManager.startScan();
   result = mWifiManager.getScanResult();

   ArrayList<String> ssids = new ArrayList<String>();
   if (result != null) {
      for (ScanResult scan : resultList) {
           ssids.add(scan.SSID);
      }
   }
   return ssids;  
}
```

if I `Log.d("DDD", "result->" + result)` on kitkat device, current wifi ap show.

but on marshmallow device. null value..

so, I search google.

first I add manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

and add `manifest check code`

```
private List<String> result;
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.scan_btn) {
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
                 checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { 
          requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 111};
       } else {
              result = getScanWifiResult();
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 111) {
            result = getScanWifiResult();
        }
    }
```

also, marshmallow device wifi scan value null.

how to get wifi scan result on android marshmallow devices?